# How to open multiple json files in Python?

Tags: json

I have to open a lot of json files in python. The following code works fine for a small amount of json files. But im already waiting 6 hours now and it's still not working. Im sure there should be a faster way than this.

```
base_dir = 'All Datasets EDIT/airlinesjson'
json_data_firstmonth2 = pd.DataFrame()
json_data_fmnoreset = pd.DataFrame()

for file in os.listdir(base_dir):
    if 'json'  in file:
        json_path = os.path.join(base_dir, file)
        json_data = pd.read_json(json_path, lines=True)
        json_data_fmnoreset = pd.concat([json_data_fmnoreset,json_data], sort=False)

json_data_firstmonth2 = json_data_fmnoreset.reset_index()
```

Comment: 6 hours is a long time. Can you provide more information about the size of the data: will it fit into memory? What is your environment? Perhaps you could use multiprocessing to make the reads concurrent.

Comment: @ggorlen, the size of the data is around 22,5 gb.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this piece of code

```
json_list = [f for f in os.listdir(base_dir) if f.endswith('.json')]
for i in json_list:
    with open(base_dir+ i) as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
        ...
```